# Thread Pool problems - Collecting files

Tags: java, threadpool, executorservice

I need to serialize into an `ArrayList` all absolute files paths from a location. I want do that with a `FixedThreadPool` from `ExecutorService`.

Example- `location: c:/folder1`; folder1 have more folders inside, all with files. I want every time I find a folder search their files to add to ArrayList.

```
public class FilePoolThreads extends Thread {

    File fich;
    private ArrayList al1;

    public FilePoolThreads(File fi, ArrayList<String> al) {
        this.fich = fi;
        this.al1 = al;
    }

    public void run() {
        FileColector fc = new FileColector();
        File[] listaFicheiros = fich.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < listaFicheiros.length; i++) {
            if (listaFicheiros[i].isFile()) {
                al1.add(listaFicheiros[i].getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The class which I begin the collection of files:

```
public class FileColector {

private ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();

public static ArrayList<String> search(File fich,ArrayList<String> list1) {


    int n1 = 1;
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n1);
    do {
        //  FilePoolThreads[] threads=new FilePoolThreads[10];
        FilePoolThreads mt = new FilePoolThreads(fich, list1);

        executor.execute(mt);

    } while (fich.isDirectory());

    executor.shutdown();

    return list1;
}
```

My code is not working well, I think I have some fails of logic, I need someone help me fix it and how can I return the `ArrayList`? I have to use the `getInputStream` before and then the `getOutputStream`?

Comment: Remember that `ArrayList` is not thread safe. You could replace with a `Vector`.

Comment: madth3 Can I use the `Collections.synchronizedList?` Whatever, I think that is not the main problem.

Comment: I did not think that was the problem either, that's why it was just a comment. Sure `synchronized` is fine.

Comment: Umm... the `fich` variable is never updated in your do loop. That's a problem.

Comment: Yes I think it too, but can I use the recursivity here to search the subfolders?

Comment: You could use recursion here. In order to do that, inside the `search` method you would loop through the children of `fich` and call `search` again with any child that is a directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is apparently an academic exercise, I'll give an overview of how I would approach this problem given your requirement that you use an executor thread pool.

First, you need to analyze the problem and break it into repeatable units of work that can be done independently of each other. In this case, the basic unit of work is processing a single filesystem directory. Each time you process a directory, you will:

- Examine each directory entry.
- If the directory entry is a regular file, add it to your list.
- If the directory entry is a sub-directory, submit it to be processed.

Next, you need to create an implementation of `Runnable` to encapsulate the processing of this basic unit of work. Each instance of the class that you create will need at least the following information:

- The `File` representing the directory it is to process.
- A list, shared between all workers, to add files to (and, as others have pointed out, `ArrayList` is not a suitable data structure for this).
- A reference to the executor service, for submitting tasks for the sub-directories.

Finally, you would need to create a worker for the top-level directory to process; submit it to the executor service; and then wait until all workers have finished processing. This last part might be the trickiest - you might need to keep a running count, using an `AtomicInteger` that you pass to each worker, to keep track of how many workers are currently processing.

Comment: That is really helpful. So, my first question about those steps. I process the sub-directory inside the process that is currently running? Work inside another work? Another question, can it be `Callable` instead `Runnable`?

Comment: No - inside the process that is running, you would create a new worker for each sub-directory and submit it to the executor service to be run in another thread. If you do the work inside the same process, it will all get done in the same thread and there's no point in using an executor service.

Comment: Ok,I understood the first three steps. On the 4th step I can pass it on the contrutor like I have in my first code, true? 5th step how I do it? How Can I share the list between all workers? If I use the runnable I can't use the callable at the same time to return the list of each work..

Comment: Probably the simplest thing to do would be to pass the file, list, and executor service in constructors to the Runnable (similar to the code you already posted). There's no need to return the list because it's shared between all the Runnables.

Answer (score 1):

Don't extend `Thread` to pass your task to an exectuor. Implement `Runnable` instead!

Or, implement [`Callable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) which can return a result when it's finished executing.

Then you can pass your tasks to [`ExecutorService.submit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.util.concurrent.Callable%29) and get back a [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) to `get()` the result of each task's computation when it is done.

Note that you will probably want to *recursively* visit sub-directories, so that you need to find both files *and* directories before adding the *files* to your output and creating new tasks for the *directories*.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for threading here, and you have several errors related to trying to use threads. My advice is to forget threading and just solve your real problem, which can be done very simply with something like [commons-io FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#iterateFiles%28java.io.File,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter%29):

```
Iterator<File> files = FileUtils.iterateFiles(directoryToScan, FileFileFilter.FILE, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
List<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
for (File file : files) {
    paths.add(file.getAbsolutePath);
}
```

That's all.

Comment: I need to use the pool threads, It's for a academic work, Whatever I think if I have to read and collect my all entire hard drive it'll be more fast with threads.

Comment: Not necessarily, but if you must use threads, start out by [understanding them](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/). The safest and easiest way to use threads in Java is to never have shared mutable state, so think how you would give each thread a chunk of work to do that's isolated from all other threads. You can submit [Callables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) to an ExecutorService to do some work in a thread and get a result back.